# LWC datatable not rendering modified column

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

```
  @track data;
  @track columns = [{
                label: 'Name',
                fieldName: 'Name',
                type: 'text',
                sortable: true
            }]

    @wire(getAccountlist)
    accountList({data,error}){
    if(data){
   this.data= data;
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

      this.columns.push({label : 'Info',
                          ...this.data[i].Info__c&& {fieldName:'Info__c'},type: 'text',sortable: true})
    }
    }
}
```

The column that I'm dynamically adding is not being added to the data table.

Comment: I had no issue adding new columns dynamically in my wiredReturn method so I think there is something wrong with the syntax of the push statement, specifically ...this.data[i].Info__c&& {fieldName:'Info__c'}

Comment: [{"label":"Name","fieldName":"Name","type":"text"},{"label":"Info","fieldName":"Info__c","type":"text"}] is what I see for the columns.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I can't gaurentee this will fix your issue as I've never tested it with data tables

`@Track` has some issues with `array.push`. Instead, I recommend creating a new array, add your column to it and set the new array to your track variable.

```
@track columns = [{
    label: 'Name',
    fieldName: 'Name',
    type: 'text',
    sortable: true
}];

@wire(getAccountlist)
accountList({data,error}){
    let newColumns = new Array();

    this.columns.forEach(item => newColumns.push(item));
    newColumns.push({
        // Build your new column
    });

    this.columns = newColumns;
}
```

**Disclaimer** I am not a js developer and my understanding of how js actually works/is interpreted is non existent. The below is my best guess explanation for why `@track` behaves this way.

The way that I think about this is that the value actually stored in `columns` is the memory address of the array object. In order to get the adapter to fire, you need to update this memory address. Just like how if this var was an integer the actual value would be a number so updating the number would fire `@track`. When an element is added to the array, the value in the tracked variable does not change and as such, the adapter never fires.

**Disclaimer:** `array.push` may work in some instances but in my experience it's more trouble then it's worth. The above is a pattern that I have been very successful with.

Comment: the @track attribute works for arrays of objects, I just tested it

Comment: on a lwc datatable array of columns for a datatable I have created, I think cartman has a syntax error

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe Thanks for the feedback. I made some changes to the language to make it less definitive and added another disclaimer at the bottom.

Comment: @CalvinOKeefe I do not see any syntax errors, in the console I can see that the columns variable has column added but the change is not being reflected on the UI

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements right (i.e. if this is a normal, run-of-the-mill dynamic behavior you're going for, and your Apex class returns a list of Accounts as it appears to be doing, based on how it's named), it sounds like maybe you're trying to add a column for each Account field returned via your Apex class.  If so, this may work better for you:

```js
@track data;
@track columns;

@wire(getAccountlist)
accountList({data,error}){
    if(data){
        this.data = data;
        this.columns = Object.keys(this.data[0])
            .reduce((cols, key) => {
                return cols.concat({
                    label: key, 
                    fieldName: key,
                    sortable: true});
            }, []);
    }
}
```

Note that if you use this approach, your column headers will be the API names of the fields in your dataset -- probably not optimal.  If you want to display the field labels instead, that's a separate solution.

Here's an example of dynamically populated columns in action: [LWC playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/uF06MlpX/1/edit)

This answer might be improved if more information is provided about the dynamic behavior you're looking for.  The way your code is formulated (`for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)`, etc.), I can't rule out that you're trying to add a column for each *row* of data in your wired Apex method's return value.  Which would be weird, unless what you're returning is not accounts but field definitions (in service of the aforementioned "separate solution").

Comment: Yes, I had also faced some weird behavior from @track variables with array push.

Comment: Please try by declaring a blank track variable first and later use the push to insert items like: @track columns =[];